# I am getting duplicate/empty form in model formset?

Tags: django

I am using model formset to populate my for with data from database. The code works fine, but it always gives me an extra empty form.

```
EventsFormSet = modelformset_factory(Events)
formset = EventsFormSet(queryset=Events.objects.filter(date__day=current_day, date__month=current_month, date__year = current_year))
return render_to_response(template_name, {"formset": formset,})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is driven by the `extra` argument. Here is [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet)

> The number of empty forms that is displayed is controlled by the extra parameter. By default, formset_factory() defines one extra form; the following example will display two blank forms:

```
EventsFormSet = modelformset_factory(Events, extra=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that. Waiting to accept the answer!